# Changing a color of a frame in QLineEdit

Tags: c++, qt

How/Can I change color of a frame in QLineEdit? What I've tried is this:

```
lineEdit->setStyleSheet("border: red");
```

and

```
lineEdit->setStyleSheet("border-color: red");
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
lineEdit->setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid red");
```